# Php query into json

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, associative

I am querying my database `Select * from Customer` the customer tables holds Name,Surname Address,age.

I want to be able to transform the query into a json object in the following object:

Customer:

```
[
    {Name:"john", Surname:"Beta" ,Age:"23"},
    {Name:"Fred", Surname:"alpha" ,Age:"31"}
];
```

Do you have any ideas?I tried to loop through the query and use merge_array.. but it MERGED the array as expected... 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Create your array, then use $returnData = json_encode($array); to format the array as JSON for returning to the browser/Ajax call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to group into the expected nested structure:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $customer[] = $row;
}

$struct = array("Customer" => $customer);
print json_encode($struct);
```

Comment: THANKS it worked.. :( I am such an ignorant for now trying it earlier... :(( I guess you never finish to learn

Answer (score 2):

If you have code like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id as userid, fullname, userstatus 
        FROM   sometable
        WHERE  userstatus = 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

seems like `json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));` would do the job? Put in a foreach/while for all results...

Comment: if I do as you say it will only fetch the first row- if I put it into a foreach loop I suppose it will always create a new json object, wouldn't?, I am trying to put that message into one json object :((

Comment: then you could loop over it and do `$arr[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` and after the loop encode the `$arr`

Answer (score 1):

Either use it yourself, or have a look at what [MySQL to JSON](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/09/23/mysql-to-json-with-php/) is doing and implement something like it :)

Answer (score 0):

Because I am using PDO to handle database calls I used a foreach statement.

```
$grids = $db->run("DATABASE QUERY");

foreach ($grids as $row) {
    $grid[] = $row;
}

$struct = array("Grid" => $grid);
print json_encode($struct);
```

Otherwise same code as above. Thanks Mario.